# Disproving that a sequence is Cauchy's Sequence

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series

$f_n=(-1)^nn$

I tried doing it this way :

Given $\epsilon>0$ we have for $n>m$

$|f_n-f_m|=|(-1)^nn-(-1)^mm|\le |(-1)^nn|+|(-1)^mm|=n+m>2m$

Am i good this far ? Now how do i conclude with this result that the sequence is not a cauchy sequence i am not getting the final statement i should make to conclude.

Aman

Comment: While trying to disprove Cauchy-ness, you can't use $\le$, you need to use $\ge$. That is because you're trying to show that 
$$
\neg ( \forall \varepsilon > 0, \exists N \text{ s.t. } \forall n,m > N, \quad |f_n - f_m| < \varepsilon )
$$
(i.e. that the sequence is NOT Cauchy, that's what the $\neg$ means), so that you want to show 
$$
\exists \varepsilon > 0, \quad \forall N, \quad \exists n,m > N \text{ s.t. } |f_n - f_m| \ge \varepsilon.
$$
Usually we work out the final inequality first and read the quantifiers later, but this means you must find some lower bound for $|f_n - f_m|$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're just fine, though you don't *really* need the inequality $\,n+m>2m\,$ .

Now just take **any** $\,0<\epsilon <1\,$ . As you've actually proved that

$$n\neq m\implies |f_n-f_m|>1$$

you are done in fact.

Comment: just one last thing to be sure, in my answer can i say that if we consider $\epsilon<2m$ we cannot find a positive integer $m$ which satisfies the cauchy's criterion for all $n\ge m$ , I understand the way you suggested but just for clarity sake :)

Comment: Well, since $\,m\in\Bbb N\,$ then saying $\,\epsilon < 2m\,$ forces $\,\epsilon <1\,$ ...Just pay attention to the fact that $\,n,m\,$ in your proof are **arbitrary** from some value on (there must exist $\,N_\epsilon\in \Bbb N\;\;s.t.\;\;n,m>N_\epsilon \ldots $ , so you better make *clear* that your epsilon is less than one.

Answer (score 2):

Verify the negation of the Cauchy's definition:

Take $\epsilon =\frac{1}{2}$ then for all $p\in \mathbb N$ there's $n=p+1,m=p$, $n\geq m\geq p$ such that:$$|f_n-f_m|=|(-1)^{p+1}(p+1)-(-1)^pp|=|p+1-p|=1>\epsilon$$

Answer (score 0):

A Cauchy sequence of integer values is eventually constant (i.e. constant for all but finitely many indices).  Therefore your sequence is not Cauchy.